# Webmachine dispatch.conf: how to bind to /

Tags: erlang, webmachine

I am working on a hello world webmachine application. What I want is that all requests are mapped to blogtest_resource except if it starts with "static". In this case, it is mapped to static_resource.

```
{["static", '*'], static_resource, [{root, "./deps"}]}.
{[], blogtest_resource, [{root, "."}]}.
```

This works nicely if I request / or anything inside static, but it fails if I request /new (which should be handled by blogtest_resource).

Is there something I am not aware of in the configuration of dispatch.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not much familiar with the webmachine but I think the second dispatch map data should be

```
{['*'], blogtest_resource, [{root, "."}]}.
```

Answer (score 1):

with just `{['*'], some_resource, [{root, "."}]}` everything will be mathed so it should be the last pattern to match.